# How can I reference a JavaScript file on every page? (ASP.NET 1.1)

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have an old ASP.NET 1.1 site that I am maintaining.  We are working with Google to place analytics code on all pages.  Since I can't take advantage of master pages in 1.1, I have my pages include headers/footers/sidebars with User Controls.

What came to mind first is to place the JavaScript in my footer ascx control so it appears on every page.  But I don't think I can link to a JavaScript file from a user control.

Any ideas on what I can do to get this js code placed on every page in my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a base page class and load the script in base page. Further inherit all pages from base page.

Other way could be same as that suggested by Tomalak

```
HtmlGenericControl jscriptFile = new HtmlGenericControl();
jscriptFile.TagName = "script";
jscriptFile.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
jscriptFile.Attributes.Add("language", "javascript"); 
jscriptFile.Attributes.Add("src", ResolveUrl("myscriptFile.js"));
this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(myJs);
```

Comment: The solution for me was to create a base page and register the javascript.

Answer (score 5):

What keeps you from simply referencing your script in the user control?

```
<asp:SomeControl ID="SomeControl1" runat="server>
  <script src="some.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</asp:SomeControl>
```

You could also do this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Literal some_js = new Literal();
  some_js = "<script type='text/javascript' src='some.js'></script>";
  this.Header.Controls.Add(some_js);
}
```

*(Obviously, the second approach would still force you to modify the pages themselves, unless they inherit from a common parent you control.)*

Comment: Apprach 1 should work just fine - just put the analytics code into the HTML portion of the user control.